# Find all $z$ if $z - n^2 = m^4$ and $(n+1)^2 - z = 2^m$

Tags: number-theory

I got this problem and was working hours at it and I just can't come up with an answer. Couldn't find one on the internet either. So please help me solve this.

Solve for all real numbers of $z \le 100000$, where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers, that fulfills both equations:

$z - n^2 = m^4$

and

$(n+1)^2 - z = 2^m$

Comment: the exclamation in the title might not be the best placed.

Comment: is $n,m$ in $z-n^2=m^4$ are the same in $(n+1)^2-z=2^m$ ?

Comment: Ýes they are the same variables.

Comment: hint: what's the change between n^2 and (n+1)^2 when it comes to natural numbers lets start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $2^m=(n+1)^2-z=n^2-z+2n+1=-m^4+2n+1$

From $2n+1=2^m+m^4$ it is easy to see that $m$ needs to be either $0$ or odd.

Reciprocally in addition to solution $(0,0,0)$ any odd $m$ defines an unique $n=\frac 12(2^m+m^4-1)$ and an unique $z=n^2+m^4$.

It's not difficult then to study $f(x)=x^4+\frac 14(2^x+x^4-1)^2\quad$ [... it is strictly $\nearrow$]

So as soon as $z=f(m)$ is greater than your given $Z_{max}$, you have found all solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Since $m$ variable is in the $2^m$, so it get to big numbers very quickly , so we can give it a fixed values to arrive at 2 equations with 2 unknowns,

$m=0$ we get that $n=0,z=0$.

$m=1$ we get that $n=1,z=2$.

$m=2$ we get that there is integer solution.

$m=3$ we get that $n=44,z=2017$.

$m=4$ we get that there is integer solution.

$m=5$ we get that $n=328,z=108209$.

$m=6$ we get that there is integer solution.

$m=7$ we get that $n = 1264, z = 1600097$